# Enum.TryParse and Enum.IsDefined returns false for char Enums

Tags: c#, enums

I have my program as below:

```
using System;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char _status = 'C';            
            Console.WriteLine(_status.ToString());            

            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyStatus), _status.ToString()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes1");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No1");
            }

            MyStatus myStatus; 
            if(Enum.TryParse(_status.ToString(), true, out myStatus))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes2");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No2");
            }
        }

        public enum MyStatus
        {
            None = 'N',
            Done = 'C'
            //Other Enums
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting "Yes1" and "Yes2" in my Console, but looks like it is returning false for the TryParse and IsDefined. Any helps are appreciated.

The code can be accessed at http://rextester.com/CSFG46040

**Update**

This value basically comes from a database and gets mapped to a character field. I also need to get it exposed to the programs which already uses this character field as an Enum. The Enum.IsDefined or Enum.TryParse is just to make sure that I am not getting any other junk characters which would get resolved to None.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Enum.TryParse` is for parsing the *Names* of enum elements or a string representation of the underlying numeric value (e.g. `"123"` for `123`). If you already have the actual value as a `char`, you can use a cast:

```
char _status = 'C'
var status = (MyStatus)_status;
```

If you're worried that it might not be one of the valid values, you can combine this with `Enum.IsDefined()`:

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyStatus), (int)_status))
{
    var status = (MyStatus)_status;
    Console.WriteLine(status);
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid value.");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that's because your enum is effectively:

```
public enum MyStatus
{
    None = 78,
    Done = 67
}
```

So "N" is neither the name of an enum value, nor is it the decimal representation. Both "None" and "78" would parse to `MyStatus.None`, but "N" won't.

It sounds like you quite possibly want a `Dictionary<char, MyStatus>`. If you want to treat the numeric value of each enum value as a char, you could build that with:

```
var dictionary = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyStatus))
                     .Cast<MyStatus>()
                     .ToDictionary(x => (char) x);
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Jon's Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38380040/209259), per the documentation [Char is also not a valid base type for c# enums](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

Excerpt:

> The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong.

I would assume that the Char is being [Implicitly converted to another type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) automagically.